# Como enviar $array com o método Post no laravel?

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, guzzle

ERRO RETORNADO

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   post.

MINHA ROTA

```
Route::post('/boleto-create', function () {

        $data = array(

            'amount' => 1,
            'due_date' =>  '2019-08-03',
            'customer_document_number' => ' "1"',
            'description' => "",
            'discount_type' => '"auto"',
            'discount_limit_date' => null,
            'discount_value' => null,
            'discount_percentage' => null,
            'payer' => [
                'person_type' => 'individual',
                'name' => "Mony",
                'cnpj_cpf' => '25411417260',
                'email' =>  'nome@email.com',
                'phone_number' => "",
                'zipcode' => '29090630',
                'address' => 'Rua Alan Turing',
                'neighborhood' => 'Bairro das Laranjeiras',
                'address_number' => 42,
                'address_complement' => '2o andar',
                'city_name' => 'Vitória',
                'state' => 'ES'
            ]
        );

 $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
        $response =  $client->request(
            'POST',
            'https://api.padmoney.com/v2/bank_billets/',
            [
                   'form_params' => [
                         $data,
                ],
                'headers'        => [

                             ],
                'decode_content' => false,
            ]
        );

        return $response->getBody()->getContents();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVI TROCANDO O FORM_PARAMS POR JSON:
    Route::post('/boleto-create', function () {

```
        $data = array(

            'amount' => 1,
            'due_date' =>  '2019-08-03',
            'customer_document_number' => ' "1"',
            'description' => "",
            'discount_type' => '"auto"',
            'discount_limit_date' => null,
            'discount_value' => null,
            'discount_percentage' => null,
            'payer' => [
                'person_type' => 'individual',
                'name' => "Mony",
                'cnpj_cpf' => '25411417260',
                'email' =>  'nome@email.com',
                'phone_number' => "",
                'zipcode' => '29090630',
                'address' => 'Rua Alan Turing',
                'neighborhood' => 'Bairro das Laranjeiras',
                'address_number' => 42,
                'address_complement' => '2o andar',
                'city_name' => 'Vitória',
                'state' => 'ES'
            ]
        );

 $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
        $response =  $client->request(
            'POST',
            'https://api.padmoney.com/v2/bank_billets/',
            [
                   'json' => [
                         $data,
                ],
                'headers'        => [

                             ],
                'decode_content' => false,
            ]
        );

        return $response->getBody()->getContents();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

No Laravel, quando uma rota declarada como post indica que ela será acessível através do método HTTP POST, leia mais sobre os métodos HTTP [aqui.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

O framework lançou essa exceção por que a rota foi acessada através do método GET.
Para acessar essa rota usando o método POST use um HTTP Client como o [postman.](https://www.getpostman.com/) ou um formulário html.